# Accessing the db connection from within my code first "table" class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

Is it possible to get to the current connection from inside your code first "table" class?

I'm trying to write a MVC Multi Tenancy app (1 app, many db's) the easiest way i can think of is to pass the connection string (or tenant name) when creating the dbcontext (i've looked at other ways to do this, but don't really understand them). However once i go into the table class I cannot then access the current db connection to perform other actions i need.

**Example code**

```
public class ConnectionContext : DbContext
{
    public ConnectionContext(String connectionString) 
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        if (!this.Database.Exists())
            throw new Exception("Database does not exist");
    }

    public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
}

[Table("Table1")]
public class Table1
{
    [Key]
    public String Column1 { get; set; }

    public String Column2 { get; set; }

    public Int32 GetNoOfColumns()
    {
        using (var conn = new ConnectionContext("???")) // <-- **issue here**
        {
            //Code to get info

            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void Authorize()
    {
        using (var conn = new ConnectionContext("???")) // <-- **issue here**
        {
            this.Column2 = "Authorized";

            conn.Entry(this).State = EntityState.Modified;
            conn.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's possible in the way that I was looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make a constructor with a connection string parameter, you can create your dbcontext class like this:

```
public class ConnectionContext : DbContext
{
    public ConnectionContext() 
        : base("nameOrConnectionString")
    {
        if (!this.Database.Exists())
            throw new Exception("Database does not exist");
    }

    public DbSet<Table1> Table1 { get; set; }
}
```

And then call your connection context this way:

```
using (var conn = new ConnectionContext())
{
}
```

Comment: That won't work in this instance as this is supposed to be multi tenancy and that would just read the same connection string from the web.config wouldn't it?

Comment: Ah I see, have you looked at this post? http://romiller.com/2011/05/23/ef-4-1-multi-tenant-with-code-first/

Comment: Yeah, that one seem to be more for people that are using one database and many schema's. I'm wondering if i can use Ninject or something similar to add the context property to all the dbset's.